# Selenium VBA - Runtime Error 11 ElementyNotVisible Error element not interactable

Tags: vba, list, selenium, css-selectors, getattribute

I am using the below mentioned code for automation of Edge Browser

The code is working fine except for "If then Else" block.

The complete script is as follows

```
Dim Obj As New WebDriver
' search for company - SF 1cr and above
Sub EdgeAutoSF1CRA0()
Set Obj = New Selenium.EdgeDriver
Dim ele As WebElement
Dim By As New Selenium.By
Obj.SetCapability "ms:edgeOptions", "{""excludeSwitches"":[""enable-automation""]}"
Obj.Start "edge", ""
Obj.Get "https://*********************"
Obj.Window.Maximize

    Obj.FindElementByName("croreAccount").SendKeys ("Search")
    Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='loadSuitFiledDataSearchAction']/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/img").Click
        Obj.FindElementById("borrowerName").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value)
        Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='search-button']/ul/li[1]/div/input").Click
        Obj.Wait 30000

If Obj.FindElementByCss("#downloadReport").Attribute("Style" = "display") = "none" Then

 Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='three-icons']/ul/li[3]/a/div").Click
 Else
 Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div").Click

End If

End Sub
```

In the If then Else statement I want to search for the style attribute of the id "downloadReport" for "display :none"

The code on website is `< a href="downloadStatusReport" id="downloadReport" style="display: none;"><div class="download-icon">Download</div></a>`

However, code always evaluate the statement as False and proceeds to execute the command `"Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div").Click"`

Answer (score 0):

1. The attribute name is `style`, not capitalized `Style`.
2. You can construct the locator so that the desired style value will be a part of locator itself.
3. You can use `FindElements` instead of `FindElement` so it will return you a **list** of matching elements so as if such element found it will return a non-empty list, otherwise it would be an empty list. With this you can check if returned list is empty or not, as following:

```vb
If Not IsEmpty(Obj.FindElementsByCss("[id='downloadReport'][style*='none']")) Then
    
 Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='three-icons']/ul/li[3]/a/div").Click
 Else
 Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='downloadReport']/div").Click
    
End If
```

Comment: Obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='three-icons']/ul/li[3]/a/div").Click

Comment: Only this code is executed in both the cases, even if condition is met or not

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no merit in locating an element with *`style`* attribute set as ***`display: none;`***. Even through you locate the element, you won't be able to click on it. So the *`If`-`Then`-`Else`* logic won't work as intended.

Instead find the desired element which is ***visible*** and ***enabled*** element, so you can invoke click on it.